# Substitute for jQuery detach

Tags: jquery, detach

I'm working on a page with a Bootstrap grid; I've implemented a custom sort using jQuery. I noticed that my call to jQuery's `detach` method is the most expensive part of my sort, and can cause a visible delay--I'm animating the change in position--if I have more than a certain number of rows. For example, given 18 rows the sort takes a little under 400 ms--over 300 ms are from the call to jQuery `detach`. Here's the core of my code:

```
var rows = jQuery('.row'),
    sorted = options.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aResult = sortExtract(a), bResult = sortExtract(b), result = 0;
        if (typeof aResult == 'string') result = aResult.localeCompare(bResult);
        else if (aResult == bResult) result = 0;
        else result = (aResult < bResult ? -1 : 1);
        return result * (ascending ? 1 : -1);
    }),
    wrapper = rows.first().parent();
sorted.stop().each(function () {
    this.dataset.top = jQuery(this).position().top;
}).detach();// TODO: Detach takes a chunk of time
wrapper.append(sorted).children().each(function () {
    var row = jQuery(this).css('top', ''),
        top = 0;
    try { top = parseInt(this.dataset.top) - row.position().top; }
    catch (e) { }// Just in case
    row.css({top: top});
}).animate({top: ''});
```

The `wrapper` only contains the sortable rows. Why does `detach` take so long? How can I work around it?

Comment: can you not just use `remove()` instead?

Comment: @RobScott No. There are events attached to the rows (for expanding and collapsing), and `remove` gets rid of those events.

Comment: How about hiding them?

Comment: @Barmar Then I won't be able to animate the rows, will I? Besides, I still need to reorder them in the DOM, and hiding doesn't change that.

Comment: The next step appends them to another element. That automatically disconnects them from their original parent, so why do you need to detach them in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar Good point. Let me try that out real quick.

Comment: @Barmar Your logic is sound, but now the append is soaking up the +300ms. :(

Comment: I think that's just the browser's internal overhead for moving elements around in the DOM. If you need to move them, I suspect you're stuck with it.